# How Certificate based authentication works in IIS7.5?

Tags: iis-7.5

We have an application which has user name and password for login.

We wold like to give extra layer of security by SSL authentication so that those broweser having certificates can access the website and then  user with valid user name and password can login.

Can SSL can be used on this context?

In IIS7.5 is there any correct procedure to achive this?

We have SSL working correctly on website however anybody can open the website with if he/she knows link. I want to restrict to those having computers having certificate provided by us.

Thank you in advance.